# How to prevent user close my application? (Linux Touchscreen apps)

Tags: java, linux, touchscreen

I would like to have an application running in a linux box with a touchscreen monitor.
I don't want to use Flash player (with full window size), so my question is, what I should use instead of a Flash Player?

This box is gonna be in a place with a lot of kids, so they can close the application and shutdown the machine XD.

I'm not a Sr. Java developer, so I don't know if theres something over there to block the 'close window' feature in an java application.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using swing, you could use `Frame.setUndecorated(true)` and maximize it. There is also the option of [exclusive full screen mode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html). From there, you'll have to unbind any global keys that map to window-exiters/taskmanagers/other-utils.

You may also want a watcher/spawner script setup to make sure your app stays up. I bet there is a more elegant way to do this but most window managers try to avoid an app doing this due to malicious possibilities.

Comment: Hey! It sounds good, I'm hardcoding my code without any IDE right now,  but thanks for your suggestion, you are right about unbid the window-exiters, taskmanagers.